# использование разных операционных систем

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Ребята, можно ли использовать дистрибутив линукса - Kali Linux, как основную операционную систему и можно ли использовать 2 дистрибутива линукса, например: Ubuntu и Kali Linux?

Comment: Можно, только зачем? А чтобы советовать - вы уж определитесь какая вам область надобна.

Comment: Ну хороший программист должен знать много языков программирования, вот думаю, какой дистрибутив лучше для белого хакера и многих используемых языков программирования

Comment: Винда, например, хороша. Отладчик в Visual Studio - лучший из того что я видел. WinDBG работает только в винде. HIEW тоже только под винду...

Comment: Linux лучше по многим показателям и не люблю винду, самое главное из за того, что никакой кондефициальности

Comment: Если линух лучше - зачем спрашивать? А конфиденциальность вы проверяли не сами.

Comment: Выбор дистрибутива для разработки не принципиален, различия есть, но, как правило, когда человек посидел достаточно в одном дистрибутиве, ему легко освоить разницу между привычным и новым.

Answer (score 2):

> можно ли использовать дистрибутив линукса - Kali Linux, как основную операционную систему

Можно, если в этом дистрибутиве имеются все средства, которые вам необходимы.

> можно ли использовать 2 дистрибутива линукса, например: Ubuntu и Kali Linux?

Да, Grub позволяет использовать несколько ОС. Они должны быть установлены в разных разделах диска.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню, при установке убунты и других подобных дистрибутивов через графический инсталлятор, там сразу на этапе выбора разделов предлагают установить новую систему **рядом** с уже имеющейся. Причём по идее не нужно даже новых разделов создавать (возможно инсталлятор делает это автоматически, не знаю).